# Imprimindo array com console.log está dando resultado diferente de acessar diretamente

Tags: javascript

Gente, quando imprimo o array 'vertical', obtenho o seguinte:

> (30) [0, 0, 0, 3.21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 104.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, _chartjs: Object, push: function, pop: function, shift: function, splice: function…]

Eis o código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var horizontal = [];
 var vertical = [];
 var backgroundColor = [];
 var borderColor = [];
 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

  for(i = 0 ; i < 30; i++) {
    vertical.splice(i, 0, 0);
  }

  $.get('Classes/buscarContas.php', function(dado) {
    dado = JSON.parse(dado);
    dado.forEach(function(obj) {
      var diaMesAno = obj['dtVencimento'].split('-');
      var dia = diaMesAno[2];
      //pega o valor atual
      var valor = parseFloat(obj['valor']);
      //corrige o zero a esquerda quando necessário
      if (dia < 10)
        dia = dia.replace('0', '');

      dia = parseInt(dia);

      vertical[dia] += valor;
    }); 
  });

console.log(vertical);
```

Engraçado que quando eu acesso a posição 3 do array, ele mostra zero.
Estou usando este array pra preencher um gráfico e realmente todos os valores estão em zero, mas parece que o array não está com todos os valores em zero.
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Obrigado

Comment: Onde está o `console.log`?

Comment: Desculpa, coloquei agora. Obrigado

Comment: E onde você tenta capturar a terceira posição?

Comment: Não coloquei no código, fiz apenas um teste e apaguei depois mas capturo usando conspole.log(vertical[3]) no mesmo local do console.log(vertical)

Comment: Coloque também um json de exemplo para simplificar a reprodução do erro. Vejo que no `for` está a fazer `vertical.splice(i, 0, 0);`. A ideia é começar com os valores a `0` dentro desse `for` ? Se for será mais simples fazer diretamente `vertical[i] = 0;`

Comment: Sim, o objetivo é simplesmente zerar. Vou substituir por vertical[i] = 0.
Gente, achei que havia algum erro no array, mas o erro mesmo está no chartjs. Antes ele não mostrava nada no gráfico, por isso achei estranho. Agora, quando eu aumento o zoom ou retiro o zoom da página ou abro o console, ele mostra os gráficos. É algum bug do chartJs que não tem a ver com este tópico. Obrigado mesmo assim pela ajuda. Eu devo finalizar este tópico?